# Numpy Arrays: Slice y-values array based on threshold, then slice the x-values array correspondingly

Tags: python, numpy

Very quick question, can't find an answer with these keywords. What is a better way of doing the following?

```
t = linspace(0,1000,300)    
x0 = generic_function(t)

x1 = x0[x0>0.8]
t1 = t[t>t[len(x0)-len(x1)-1]]
```

The operation I'm using @t1 strikes me as very un-pythonic and inefficient. Any pointers?

Comment: not to mention it only works because my values increase monotonically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can simply reuse the cut array.  For example:

```
>>> from numpy import arange, sin
>>> t = arange(5)
>>> t
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y = sin(t)
>>> y
array([ 0.        ,  0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025 ])
```

As you've already done, you can make a bool array:

```
>>> y > 0.8
array([False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

and then you can use this to filter both `t` and `y`:

```
>>> t[y > 0.8]
array([1, 2])
>>> y[y > 0.8]
array([ 0.84147098,  0.90929743])
```

No use of `len` or assumptions about monotonicity involved.

Comment: actually, I have a follow-up question. what do you call that? filtering, cutting or slicing?

Comment: @RodericDay: I'd simply call it "indexing", only with an array of bools.  The numpy docs call it [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing).  Slicing is the stuff with colons, e.g. t[3:4, 2:30:5], etc.